# In Pandas, how read a Pickle file that throws Unpickling Error: invalid load key?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I'm reading a pickle file with:

```
pandas.read_pickle('data/file.pickle')
```

and it throws this error:

```
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

Note that I've seen other threads on how to solve this problem when saving the pickle file, but in my case I just need to open this specific dataframe.

Also the pickle file could contain some special characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the error "\_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ' '."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049688/what-causes-the-error-pickle-unpicklingerror-invalid-load-key)

Comment: What happens if you use the standard pickle module?

Comment: @roganjosh it happens the same thing. It seems to be some kind of encoding problem.

Comment: Do you know how the pickle was created?

Comment: @roganjosh it was created with pandas as well: dataframe.to_pickle(...)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer others can use to create such a file?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've used the same code to open many pickle files, it it works great, so I think the problem is related to the content in file, maybe the encoding (since I don't know what '\x00' means). Is there a way for me to upload the file here? I could.

Comment: @MaxU no. Only one version being used.

Comment: I could open the file with Sublime. It's only zeros. Does it mean it's corrupted or something like this?

Answer (score 7):

One of the possible explanation is pickling with compression. On my system, reading files compressed with either `xz` or `gzip` throws exception of invalid load key if I do not specify compression. In similar case, both `zip` and `bz2` raise different exceptions.

I recommend to try one of those:

```
pandas.read_pickle('data/file.pickle', 'xz')
pandas.read_pickle('data/file.pickle', 'gzip')
```

Comment: Extremely helpful answer :) Solved our problem right away. Saved us some lines of code too, since our target is a Pandas DataFrame anyways. Thanks!