# How to unpickle a file with erroneous code?

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to unpickle a file received from someone else (which is to say I don't have access to the source code). On trying `pickle.load(filename)` I get the following error:

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x01'
```

I know that the pickle file also tries to import some outdated modules and am not sure if that is causing the problem?

Some answers on SO suggest not unpickling a file that I don't trust. In that case is my only option asking the owner to send me an unpickled version?

Comment: It sounds like the object you're trying to unpickle may have some complexity to it - does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049688/what-causes-the-error-pickle-unpicklingerror-invalid-load-key

Comment: @Grismar Thanks. I believe that post was to do with multiple unpickling calls on different parts of a file, while I am just calling it once on the file as a whole.