# Elements of a Python pickle seem to be missing

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I've inherited a bit of python code that saves its output to a pickle with the following code:

```
def save_picklefile_and_close(self):
    pickle.dump({'p_index': self.p_index, 'p_val': self.p_val,
                 'z': self.z, 'w': self.w, 'nd': self.nd, 'nfg': self.nfg,
                 'lamb_scalar': self.lamb_scalar, 'PEAKSIZE': self.PEAKSIZE,
                 'N': self.N, 'S': self.S, 'F': self.F,
                 'FG': self.FG, 'q': self.q,
                 'pi': self.pi, 'phi': self.phi,
                 'p_scores': self.p_scores, 'w_scores': self.w_scores, 'z_scores': self.z_scores,
                 'likelihood': self.likelihood,
                 'p_true_val': self.p_true_val,
                 'p_true_index': self.p_true_index,
                 'w_true': self.w_true,
                 'phi_true': self.phi_true,
                 'pi_true': self.pi_true,
                 'z_true': self.z_true,
                 'z_true_per_data': self.z_true_per_data,
                 'data_for_debugging': self.data_for_debugging,
                 }, self.picklefile)
    self.picklefile.close()
```

This looks to me like a pickled dict, which there are plenty of examples of online. All of the keys are in the pickle file, e.g. `grep 'w_true' file.p` returns a match. But when I try to read the pickle with this code:

```
f = open('file.p')
p = pickle.load(f)
print "type=", type(p)
print "shape=", p.shape
print "w_true=", p.w_true
```

all I get is a single `numpy.ndarray`:

```
type= <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape= (56, 147)
w_true=
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-83ddd085f0fd> in <module>()
      3 print "type=", type(p)
      4 print "shape=", p.shape
----> 5 print "w_true=", p.w_true

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'w_true'
```

How do I access the other information in the pickle?

**UPDATE:**
Yes, I'm definitely working with the same file. This modified code:

```
f = open('/path/to/file.p', mode='rt')

p = pickle.load(f)
print "type=", type(p)
print "shape=", p.shape

i = 0
for line in f:
    if 'w_true' in line:
        print "line no.", i, ":", line
    i += 1
```

Results in:

```
type= <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape= (56, 147)
line no. 7499 : sS'w_true'
```

But there's no reason the string `w_true` (and all of the other keys from the `dict`) should be in the file if it was *only* an `ndarray`, right? My only other thought is that maybe there's something in the pickle file header that's misleading the unpickler? I.e. maybe the output code is bugged? Here's the head of `file.p`:

```
$ head -n25 file.p 
cnumpy.core.multiarray
_reconstruct
p1
(cnumpy
ndarray
p2
(I0
tS'b'
tRp3
(I1
(I56
I147
tcnumpy
dtype
p4
(S'i4'
I0
I1
tRp5
(I3
S'<'
NNNI-1
I-1
I0
tbI00
```

Comment: How on earth do you get a numpy.ndarray? Are you sure you are opening the same pickle file?

Comment: Yup--it's extremely confusing. I'll triple-check the file and update the question either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code which created the pickle opened only one file:

```
self.picklefile = open(picklefile_name, 'wb')
```

then wrote to that same file twice. First here:

```
if self.is_saving_pickle:
    pickle.dump(self.x, self.picklefile) #a single numpy.ndarray
```

and then later here:

```
def save_picklefile_and_close(self):
    pickle.dump({'p_index': self.p_index, 'p_val': self.p_val,
                 # ... snip ...
                 'data_for_debugging': self.data_for_debugging,
                 }, self.picklefile)
    self.picklefile.close()
```

When the `unpickler` went to load `file.p`, it saw and returned the first `pickle` and then stopped before touching the second. When the first write `pickle.dump()` call is commented out, `unpickling` properly returns the `dict` from the second call.

**Update:** based on @Mike McKerns' comment & links, it is also possible to call `pickle.load()` multiple times to retrieve multiple pickles made by multiple `pickle.dump()` calls within the same file.

Comment: Uh… no.  The lesson is actually if you put two pickles in a file, then you need to take two pickles out.  Two `dump` mean you need two `load`.  Try it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20725705/2379433, and similar.