# python joblib.load: Iterating over generator results in infinite loop

Tags: python, scikit-learn, generator, joblib

Below is the code I use for the generator. It is modified from [Saving and loading multiple objects in pickle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716812/saving-and-loading-multiple-objects-in-pickle-file). The file was created with joblib.dump, and consists (so far) of a single machine learning model.

```
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib

filename = 'ML_models.pkl'
def load(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield joblib.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break
```

Next I test the generator as follows:

```
models = load(filename)
for model in models:
    print model
```

Unfortunately, this prints the model repeatedly until I interrupt the kernel.
What is the right way to signal EOF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/persistence.html), `joblib.load` returns the full object.

```
def load(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        return joblib.load(f)
```

Comment: It looks like I should store my models e.g., in a dict or list, then dump that to file as a single object.

Comment: Indeed, it works if I dump multiple objects stored in a dict.