# How to load only selected objects from a pickle file?

Tags: python, memory, pickle

I have multiple pickle files which contain two lists. The first one is a lightweight list of floats, but the second one is a list of long vectors which consumes a lot of memory when loaded. How can I load only the first list from each pickle file? This is the way I currently do it:

```
import cPickle, bz2    
with bz2.BZ2File(lhl_file, "rb") as pickled_file:
    pickle_object = cPickle.load(pickled_file)
    light_list, \
    heavy_list = list(pickle_object)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pickled two lists **individually** into a pickle file, you should be able to load them individually easily.

Here is an example I adapted from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28745948/3901029), which covers more thoroughly.

```
import pickle

filename = "pickle.dat"
data1 = 'hello'
data2 = 'world'
data3 = 'buddy'

# pickle one object at at time
f1 = open(filename, "wb")
pickle.dump(data1, f1)
pickle.dump(data2, f1)
pickle.dump(data3, f1)
f1.close()

# so that you can load them one at at time
f2 = open(filename, 'rb')
print pickle.load(f2)
print pickle.load(f2)
f2.close()
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

PS: As far as I know, it's not possible to load data2 before data1. Though that is not the case for you it seems.