# Saving Jupyter notebook session

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle

I am currently trying to save my whole Jupyter Notebook environment (working throught Anaconda 3).
By environment, I mean, all the objects created (dataframes, lists, tuples, models, ...).

Unfortunately I don't have Linux even though there seemed to be Linux command solutions.
I tried finding a solution with pickle as recommended in the following topic but it seems that you have to specify which objects you want to dump and load.

[saving-and-loading-multiple-objects-in-pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716812/saving-and-loading-multiple-objects-in-pickle-file/20725705#20725705)

What I would like to do is that everything saves and loads as it can be done with `R`, where you just save and load an `.RData` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Dill`](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) to store your session

```
pip install dill
```

Save a Notebook session:

```
import dill
dill.dump_session('notebook_env.db')
```

Restore a Notebook session:

```
import dill
dill.load_session('notebook_env.db')
```